# PHP file download with headers

Tags: php, http-headers

I have problem with my PHP code:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="config.yml"');
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
header('Content-Length: '.strlen($file));
readfile($file);
```

File is downloaded well, but page will close instantly.
Like downloading will start, and page will close. But I have in page also some else code, like html.
I don't want to close page after downloading.
Can you give me some advice ? Because I don't know, where can be mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot return both the file download and html or other content in the same response.

What you need to do is return the html first and within that have a request for the download. E.g.

```
<iframe width="1" height="1" frameborder="0" src="/downloadfile.php"></iframe>
```